How to handle array values that contain commas?
I am using JavaScript and indexOf to extract metadata values from one set and map them to values in another. This is so the values are available as search filters in an asset management platform. The source metadata is stored in Keywords in Adobe PDF files. They are comma separated values e.g.
Carton (Inc Sleeve),Joe Bloggs,Chilled,Pre-Packed,AB - Mid Tier,P080D41_V1,232x356,18022,Master,39L

My script maps the above against the 10 destination values with no issues. However, there are some instances where array values contain commas:
Flow Wrap,Joe Bloggs,Core Grocery,Rice,Pasta,Foreign Food,Mid-Tier 2023,NA,475x240,19183,Master,1203

In the above keywords, Rice,Pasta,Foreign Food should be mapped to one target value, but my script splits by comma and adds them as Rice, Pasta, Foreign Food and thus breaks the mapping.
I know the keywords that contain extra commas, so I need a way of locating them in the array and mapping them as a single value to the correct target value, without breaking the sequence of the mapping.
I have tried analysing the array for matches against the exception values, but I think because I'm then splitting it via var keywords = keywordsValue.split(",") they are not recognised.

Real CSV syntax uses quoting of field values to "hide" embedded commas.

when you say "I have tried analysing the array for matches against the exception values" you mean you created a list of exceptions which includes Rice,Pasta,Foreign Food?

If that is the case, then you should first "extract" all the exceptions using replace(), and only when your string is freed of exceptions then you should split() it by commas. The way you described it, it looks like you're doing it the other way around, i.e. first split by commas and then look for exceptions, which won't work

Is there any way for you to change the code that generates the CSV? Values containing a comma should be quoted. So they should be generated as Core Grocery,"Rice,Pasta,Foreign Food",Mid-Tier 2023 (See section 2.6 in the Definition of the CSV Format)

If you know it's only the 4th field that has the troublesome data with commas in it, then you can locate the first 3 fields from the front of the string, and then locate the final 6 fields from the back, and then merge all remaining fields to form the 4th.
